# Assigning Value to Bootstrap-datetimepicker with Format MM/YYYY Displays Incorrect Year

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) version 4.17.47 in ASP MVC 4 app.

I have this model property:

```
public DateTime MonthYear { get; set; }
```

I assign default value in controller (arbitrary value is just an example actual value is determined through some logic):

```
model.MonthYear = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1);
```

I display this in view using datepicker so users can update the value as needed:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MonthYear, new { @class = "form-control input month-picker" })
```

Script:

```
$('.month-picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/YYYY',
    useCurrent: false,
    toolbarPlacement: 'bottom',
    viewMode: 'months'
});
```

The problem is the control displays "03/0001" instead of "03/2017".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well.. it really seems to be ok.. have you tried to remove the datetimepicker just to see if the TextBox is being filled with the expected data?

Comment: @drigomed when I remove the picker I got "3/1/2017 12:00:00 AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that the input is being filled with a DD/MM/YYYY date from server when datetimepicker is expecting only MM/YYYY. Try formating the textbox, like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MonthYear, "{0:MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control input month-picker" })
```

That should work.